# Matter.js animated sprites

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, matter.js

I'm getting mad trying to figure out how to put an animated image into a `Bodies.rectangle`. I've animated the image with CSS and I have a gif version of the image that I want to use. How can I do it?

```js
var char = Bodies.rectangle(90, 549, 84, 78, {
  isStatic: true,
  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: 'http://i57.tinypic.com/3343zwi.png'
    }
  }
});
```

This is my declaration of the body that I want to use. Should I use Matter.js for this kind of thing?

Comment: Maybe @liabru could help?

Comment: The built-in MJS renderer isn't really suited for this sort of task--it's mainly for prototyping. Try plugging MJS into a rendering engine that supports spritesheets and animations natively, for example Phaser, HTML5 canvas, etc. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207865/matter-js-is-there-any-way-to-animate-my-sprite/65301374#65301374) may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matter.js: is there any way to animate my sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207865/matter-js-is-there-any-way-to-animate-my-sprite)