# matter.js: is there any way to animate my sprite

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I know in traditional HTML5 canvas, we can use drawImage method (the longest one with 9 properties) and change frameX and frameY to make sprite sheet animation. But I am new to matter.js. I've checked matter.js document but still don't have any idea about how to animate my sprite. Here is my object:

```
const ball = Bodies.circle(340, 340, 10, {
  density: 0.0005,
  frictionAir: 0.06,
  restitution: 0,
  friction: 0,

  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: "images/blueMonster.png", 
      yScale: 0.2,
      xScale: 0.2,
      isStatic: true,
    },
  },
  inertia: Infinity,
  label: "ball",
});

World.add(world, ball);
```

If I need to provide more info to solve this problem, please let me know. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Welcome to SO! The built-in rendering is really for demonstration purposes. MJS can be added to your existing spritesheet code using traditional HTML5 canvas.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a fundamental misconception here. Matter.js is a physics engine that can plug into any rendering front-end. You don't have to use the built-in MJS rendering engine which is primarily there for prototyping. You can use your existing HTML5 code or something like [Phaser](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.MatterPhysics.html) which has robust support for sprite sheets.

Here's a simple proof-of-concept using vanilla JS to render a sprite animation with MJS as the physics engine. The approach is to call `Matter.Engine.update(engine);` to run the engine each frame and use `coin.position` to draw the sprite. More complex animations might use `vertices` and `angle` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64453027/6243352) and [here](https://codepen.io/ggorlen/pen/LOwrxX?editors=0010) in addition to the sprite sheet, but this is use-case dependent.

```js
(async () => {
  const image = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => resolve(image);
    image.onerror = reject;
    image.src = "https://art.pixilart.com/c7f297523ce57fc.png";
  });
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 500;
  canvas.height = 250;
  
  const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
  const coin = Matter.Bodies.circle(100, 0, 100, {
    density: 0.0005,
    frictionAir: 0.06,
    restitution: 0,
    friction: 0,
  });
  const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    0, 350, 1500, 170, {isStatic: true}
  );
  const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
    engine, {element: canvas}
  );
  Matter.Composite.add(
    engine.world, [coin, ground, mouseConstraint]
  );
  
  const w = 200;
  const h = 170;
  let frameNumber = 0;
  
  (function rerender() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const offset = (~~frameNumber * w) % image.width;
    const {x, y} = coin.position;
    ctx.drawImage(
      image,      // image
      offset,     // sx
      40,         // sy
      w,          // sWidth
      h,          // sHeight
      x - w / 2,  // dx
      y - h / 2,  // dy
      w,          // dWidth
      h           // dHeight
    );
    frameNumber += 0.1;
    Matter.Engine.update(engine);
    requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
  })();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Another approach is to plop in a gif or video--easily done since you're just making a webpage in the DOM that happens to have physics attached. See [how to round an image in matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72849934/6243352) for an example.